# How to set different wallpaper for each screen from command line in Gnome3?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, wallpaper

In gnome3 I can run the following command to set the desktop wallpaper for all my monitors:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/mypic.png
```

How can I set the wallpaper for each of my monitors individually, so that each of them can has a different wallpaper?

Looking for a command line solution.

Answer (score 1):

th usual answer is you can not.  The way you do it is to create one huge picture, and it will span all your monitors.  "there is app for that" and it works pretty good.  There is very little customisation, but you can use it from the command line.

https://gitlab.com/gabmus/HydraPaper#using-from-the-command-line

install via flatpak, on Ubuntu or Debian

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
sudo flatpak install flathub org.gabmus.hydrapaper
```

run the GUI `flatpak run org.gabmus.hydrapaper` or use the CLI `hydrapaper -c path_to_wallpaper1 path_to_wallpaper2 ...`

This automatically "builds" the large image for you.